# Javascript plugin not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari

I have installed a plugin in Wordpress. The plugin name is soundy background music. The plugin is working in all browsers except working Safari: the sound does not play and button pause not working.

The error is:

> typeerror undefined is not a function
>   (evaluating _this.audio_player_element.pause()')

this is link for download file js

https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/c2169c2ad8096778decaed1df7304cd520160530203306/397086fa9a12eba87669072851c7e0da20160530203306/33f9d1

Comment: Where is `_this` defined?

Comment: start code javascript <code>war_SoundyFrontEnd.prototype.initPPButton = function()
{
 var _this = this;</code>

Comment: Please edit your question to add the expanded code snippet rather than adding code in the comments

Comment: What's the name of the plugin?

Comment: the plugin name is  soundy background music. I have paste link for download file js

Answer (score 1):

1) as there is .attr(), I assume you are using jQuery
   you might be using more than one jquery script (racing each another).

2) as there is _this you are scoping and you might actually be calling object that is out of the scope.

3) if the script you are using does not work for Safari, then this is what is happening.

```
if( _this.audio_player_element.paused )
   {
     //you will never reach this because audio_player_element is undefined which gives false due to your scope or being taken by another jquery $ script
   }
        else
   {
    //you will always end up here, and you are trying to pause() the undefined.
   }
```

Comment: I have paste link for download file js.